# Android Login monitoring using Foreground service

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a login status monitoring in my application. What I am trying to achieve is calling an API in background service continuously. It will give a response depending on if the user is eligible to remain logged in. If the response states the user is not eligible to remain logged in, then the app should log out.

**How I Implemented this**

I created a foreground service and called the API inside an `AsyncTask` method. I called this method inside the service's `onStartCommand()` method.

**My doubts**

1. Is this the proper way to implement this work flow?.
2. I called the login activity from service like this

```
    Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(BluetoothLeService.this,SplashScreen.class);
    dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

How do I finish the Activity from the service?

**EDIT- Why Iam trying this way**

If a user's activation is removed manually from back end then according to this work flow app will sign out automatically.Basically my app is a BLE based alert system.So logout after certain time is not possible.The only situation for logout is if the back end (ie; the service providers) find that user is not eligible for using the service, they will change the mentioned API result is to false.Due to this scenario I calls the API all time.What will be a better workaround for this?

Comment: "Is this the proper way to implement this work flow?" -- no. "calling an API in background service all time" is terrible for the user from a battery and bandwidth standpoint. Check while your app is in the foreground, please, at which point you no longer need a service.

Comment: What happen if a user's activation is removed manually from back end and app is offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your task much easier than you can imagine. As for me I use tokens for authorization and further service usage. I think that call API in service will make your app to work slowly.

So, I use retrofit in my app development and I think that in your project you use this library or volley. And what about tokens? After successful login I receive two tokens: `access_token`+`refresh_token`. First token is used for getting ordinary info. And refresh_token is used for updating access_token. If your refresh_token will be expired you have to logout from your app. And don't try to send `API` request in background it is bad idea.

Main schema of using tokens: login -> getting two tokens (access+refresh) -> using access_token in ordinary request (get data from API or send smth) -> refresh tokens with using `refresh_token`

So, for example at my server I use 0,5 hour between token refreshing. `Refresh_token` won't be valid until your access_token will get expired.

For example [article](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/android-retrofit-2-refresh-access-token-with-okhttpclient-and-authenticator) about this tokens.

handling error in okhttp:

```
 private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    public void run() throws Exception {
      Request request = new Request.Builder()
          .url("url_url_url")
          .build();

      client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
          if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

          System.out.println(response.body().string());
        }
      });
    }
```

### UPDATE

So the last variant of solution: create class which will contain method with api call. You will call this method before every request. This method will return true/false. If false - you will logout from your app, if true - continue working with app. Good luck :)

Comment: Hi, The problem is this scenorio is what customer want because.The purpose is if a user's activation is manually removed from backend side, then the app will logout .

Comment: so you know about token usage? when user activation is removed you can logout automatically after getting appropriate message from server. Which library are you using?

Comment: Iam using OkHttp

Comment: and you can receive some messages from server?

Comment: Yes bro. The flow is when user is logged in first time a unique id will get. I store this ID. Then this unique ID will send to the API mentioned above. It will give the response as user activation is active or inactive. Due to this I placed the API call in service. Whenever the response as user activation is inactive, app will signout

Comment: don't place api calls in service. it is totally bad idea. I will suggest you to handle server message and then work with it. Do you have the example of this answer when user doesn't have his id?

Comment: Id will get when user logged in first time bro

Comment: Then how can I achieve this bro?

Comment: for example you can remove your id via backend and see the example of this message

Comment: when you will receive the appropriate answer you will be automatically logged out

Comment: if our ID is valid, then the json response contains ;is_deactivated' propety which will be "ACTIVE". If the user ID is invalid then the json response will be "INACTIVE".

Comment: which library are you using at your project? retrofit or volley?

Comment: Bro Iam using OkHttp for making API calls

Comment: I have edited my answer with handling errors, when you will receive the message of inactive id you will have to logout

Comment: Bro thanks for the edit. But if user's Activation is set to Not Active in back end, then how can I manage this with tokkens?

Comment: I don't understand you :( you receive response from server and you can handle this error

Comment: Bro sorry for misclarification.I am not much familiar with tokkens.The problem is my Client wants handle this scenerio according to this API call.I dont want the app to logout after a certain period of time.What I want is the backend(ie; the company) can make a app users app to logout if the user is become uneligible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194049/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and-androdevil).

Answer (score 0):

You should do the login monitoring on Clint side instead of calling and api, which will be a better option.

You can use a countdown timer of a fix time for the time management.

Whenever there is some event occurred you can restart the timer.

Depending upon the inactivity time (when timer finished) you can send the user to the login activity again.

Handling a service with a regular api call is not a right option.

But if you required a regular api call and if it is the final option, In that case timer will be a far better option as compared to service

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thansk for the reply.My client asked me to do it according to regular API call.

Comment: if this helped you rate the answer